# Magento 2 eWay Payment Gateway Error - A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again

Tags: payment, magento2.3.4

Eway payment getting an error **A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again**

[image]

**Note :** Amount received in eWAY payment gateway, but order not created in magento2.

**ewayrapid_debug.log : https://justpaste.it/8qla2**

Comment: Could you check the error log in var/log/exception.log file?

Comment: @RenjithR My exception.log error https://justpaste.it/758ai

Comment: Did you talk with eWay team? They will be able to help you out. Also, look for this line of exception: `Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line`. You should find this in server log or `var/log/exception.log`.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Eway team also told check Magento log, my exception.log file https://justpaste.it/3zj43

Comment: May I know if you had migrated M1 to M2 and you were using "M2e" extension in M1? Also, does it happens every time or only sometimes?

Comment: I had a similar problem, does it do the same with other online payment methods? If it does might be other extension causing that, in my case was an invoice extension that was installed, it uses SalesOrderAfterSave observer and messed with the order creation of online payment methods

Answer (score 1):

To know the exact reason, update the following core file:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

Please comment out the try-catch same as below:

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    // try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    // } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
    //     throw new CouldNotSaveException(
    //         __($e->getMessage()),
    //         $e
    //     );
    // } catch (\Exception $e) {
    //     $this->getLogger()->critical($e);
    //     throw new CouldNotSaveException(
    //         __('A server error stopped your order from being placed. Please try to place your order again.'),
    //         $e
    //     );
    // }
    return $orderId;
}
```

Now, try to place order again. You will be able to see the detailed error in log file or may be in Browser > Inspect Element > Network.

**Note:** Please do not forget to revert the core file after updating the code.

Comment: There is no module-checkout folder under vendor/magento https://snipboard.io/PSnvb8.jpg   How to edit the file?  @Pratik Oza

Comment: Find this path: app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php OR check symlink folder.

Comment: Yes, found it, now error like https://snipboard.io/d9gYuj.jpg

Comment: Please refer [this](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5357) link.

Comment: For my clarity, does 2.1.x code support 2.3.x?

Comment: You can implement the workaround on your staging environment. May be it will resolve your issue.

Comment: The link you sharing specifically telling shipping address, in my case not mentioned that. Generally said Array to convert string along with path that's all. Shall I try your suggestion link.

Comment: As I've mentioned, you can implement the workaround on your staging environment based on provided solutions OR need to dig out more in the codebase.
Refer logged issue [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12612).

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the same message had to do with RabbitMQ credentials. As explained in this link https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/rabbitmq.html
to connect with RabbitMQ on Magento you should insert in app/etc/env.php these credentials: `

```
'amqp' =>
array (
  'host' => 'yourhost.example.com',
  'port' => '5672',
  'user' => 'magento',
  'password' => 'magento',
  'virtualhost' => '/'
 ),
```

),
`